# Is it possible to update a pygame drawing attribute when clicking in a cell of a grid?

Tags: python, pygame, grid

I'm approaching PyGame but I stepped on a problem: I am trying to draw a grid made out of single rectangle drawings, I want each one of those rectangle to fill or empty when the left mouse button is released on said rectangle. The grid i represented by a matrix of tuples each one representing each rectangle formatted like this (column, row) to be in line with pygame pixel's coordinates, then I create another matrix of tuples to convert from mouse position tuples (colpixel, rowpixel) to rectangle tuples, I also created a dictionary that pairs rectangle tuples as keys with a value that can be 1 or 0, that value represents whether the rectangle is filled or not, that is the value that I change when the mouse button is released. Here is the code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

SCREEN_WIDTH = 40
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 20

DIM = 20

ROWS = int(SCREEN_HEIGHT / DIM)
COLUMNS = int(SCREEN_WIDTH / DIM)


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

pygame.display.set_caption('Game of Life')


# filling rect_matrix with tuple, each one representing a rectangle of the grid (columns, rows).
# filling rect_map by pairing the tuples from rect_matrix with a value that can be 0 or 1, default 1.
rect_matrix = []
rect_map = {}

for i in range(ROWS):
    temp = []
    for j in range(COLUMNS):
        temp.append(pygame.Rect((j * DIM, i * DIM), (DIM, DIM)))
        rect_map[(j, i)] = 1
    rect_matrix.append(temp)


# filling mouse_to_rectangle, sort of a decoder to convert from groups of tuples
# (representing mouse coordinates in pixels) to a single tuple (representing single rectangles)
mouse_to_rectangle = []

ii = 0
for i in range(SCREEN_WIDTH):
    jj = 0
    temp = []
    for j in range(SCREEN_HEIGHT):
        temp.append((ii, jj))
        if ((j + 1) % DIM == 0):
            jj += 1
    if ((i + 1) % DIM == 0):
        ii += 1
    mouse_to_rectangle.append(temp)


is_running = True

while is_running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            is_running = False
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:

            if rect_map[mouse_to_rectangle[pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0]][pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1]]] == 1:
                rect_map[mouse_to_rectangle[pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0]][pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1]]] = 0
            else:
                rect_map[mouse_to_rectangle[pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0]][pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1]]] = 1



    for i, ii in zip(rect_matrix, range(len(rect_matrix))):
        for j, jj in zip(i, range(len(i))):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (100, 100, 100), j, rect_map[(jj, ii)])

    pygame.display.update()
```

I managed to fill (relative value in rect_map goes to 1) a rectangle upon releasing the left button when pointing it but when I try to click again on a rectangle that is now filled it won't empty. I represented the "filled or not" property with ones or zeroes beacuse the rectangle is filled when the `width` parameter in `pygame.draw.rect` is set to 0, if a `>0` value is used then the rectangle will have a border as thick as the specified value in pixel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed to clear the display before drawing the grid. Thus all the rectangles which hav been draw stayed there for ever:

```py
screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
```

Anyway you've over complicated the algorithm. The position in the grind can be computed by dividing the components of the mouse position by `DIM` (`//` (floor division) operator):

```py
mousepos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
gridpos = mousepos[0] // DIM, mousepos[1] // DIM
```

Finally it the grid state can be changed with ease and `mouse_to_rectangle` is not need at all:

```py
if rect_map[gridpos] == 1:
    rect_map[gridpos] = 0
else:
    rect_map[gridpos] = 1
```

See the example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()

SCREEN_WIDTH = 200
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 200

DIM = 20

ROWS = int(SCREEN_HEIGHT / DIM)
COLUMNS = int(SCREEN_WIDTH / DIM)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('Game of Life')

# filling rect_matrix with tuple, each one representing a rectangle of the grid (columns, rows).
# filling rect_map by pairing the tuples from rect_matrix with a value that can be 0 or 1, default 1.
rect_matrix = []
rect_map = {}

for i in range(ROWS):
    temp = []
    for j in range(COLUMNS):
        temp.append(pygame.Rect((j * DIM, i * DIM), (DIM, DIM)))
        rect_map[(j, i)] = 1
    rect_matrix.append(temp)

is_running = True

while is_running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            is_running = False
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:

            mousepos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            gridpos = mousepos[0] // DIM, mousepos[1] // DIM
            if rect_map[gridpos] == 1:
                rect_map[gridpos] = 0
            else:
                rect_map[gridpos] = 1

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    for i, ii in zip(rect_matrix, range(len(rect_matrix))):
        for j, jj in zip(i, range(len(i))):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (100, 100, 100), j, rect_map[(jj, ii)])

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Thank you!! I totally forgot to clean the screen and tanks also for the suggestion on the overall algorithm.