# detecting position of image but it highlights full chess column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Ive been trying to make a chess game in Pygame and ive managed to draw the board, and all the pieces. Now im moving onto detecting if a piece has been clicked, but it says the piece has been selected in all the column (BISHOP)

```py
def detectClick():
     pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        
     if (0,0) <= pos <= (50,50):
          print('bb')
```

Ive tried math, but to no success. I have no clue as to why this bit isnt working

Comment: how is trying to compare if the coordinates of the mouse are in the rectangle with diagonal (0,0) to (50,50) going to detect a click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (0,0) <= pos <= (50,50):` does not do what you expect. When comparing tuples, the first pair of elements that are not equal always determines the result of the comparison. Therefore, if the first elements are unequal, the others are not considered at all. You are trying to use the tuple for a 2D box test where both coordinates must satisfy a condition. You need to compare the items component by component

```py
if 0 < pos[0] < 50 and 0 < pos[1] < 50:
```

In pygame you can use `pygame.Rect.colliderect` to test if a point is in a rectangle:

```py
rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 50, 50)
if rect.collidepoint(pos):
```

However to get the column and row of a point in a grid you just need the `//` (floor division) operator e.g. for a grid with a cell size of 50:

```py
pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
column = pos[0] // 50
row = pos[1] // 50
```

---

Also see

- [Is it possible to update a pygame drawing attribute when clicking in a cell of a grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61551790/is-it-possible-to-update-a-pygame-drawing-attribute-when-clicking-in-a-cell-of-a)
- [How do I detect collision in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640685/how-do-i-detect-collision-in-pygame)
- [Pygame mouse clicking detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990137/pygame-mouse-clicking-detection)
- [python pygame mouse events not working and not raising errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67437709/python-pygame-mouse-events-not-working-and-not-raising-errors)